# check already registered email without submit and display the error using an image not echo message

Tags: php, forms, registration

Please help me out...
I'm creating a multistage sign up form,
on my first step user is asked for email,password and confirm password...
so when email input is typed and user enters the password, i need the script to be run in background for checking availability of email id, and if not available then message should be shown via image not echo message, so in short all these happens without submit ...
and I'm using PHP
please help me out...

Thanks in advance

This is HTML:

```
            <input type="password" id="signuppassword" name="signuppassword" class="register-input" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="password" id="signup-cpassword" name="signup-cpassword"  class="register-input" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" id="first-next" value="" />
```

Comment: We need to know are you using database or text file for saving the user data.

Comment: like google, it shows dynamically that this username is available without submit

Comment: You need to use AJAX for this, see jQuery ajax's documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: As you have been advised, you surely needs an ajax call that will execute preferably on `blur` event of email text box checking availability of email. Please put some code also/or what have you tried to increase probability of getting a appropriate response.

Comment: yeah i'm using on blur event but i'm very new to php coding and really don't know how to use ajax...

Comment: <input type="text" id="signupemail" name="signupemail" class="register-input" autofill='off' placeholder="E-mail" />
    <input type="password" id="signuppassword" name="signuppassword" class="register-input" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" id="signup-cpassword" name="signup-cpassword"  class="register-input" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" id="first-next" value="" />

Comment: at default the next button is hidden and i want it to be shown only when email is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give ur email field a class or Id n use the folling function.

```
 $("#email").blur(function() 
    {
    var searchbox = $(this).val().trim();
    checkEmailExistance(searchbox);
    });//end on blur
```

`function  checkEmailExistance(searchbox){

var dataString = 'searchword='+ searchbox.trim();
            if(searchbox=='')
              {
              }
                else
                {

                $.ajax({

                type: "POST",

                url: '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/register/email_validation"; ?>',
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(dataString)
                {
                if(dataString=="0"){
                    $("#error").text("This is Unique Address");
                       $("#error").attr('isverified','1');
                   }else
                    {
                          $("#error").text("This email address is already present");
                           $("#error").attr('isverified','0');
                    }


                }

                });//end ajax
                };`

Comment: in url put your php url where you have written mysql query. and just change class name of ur email text box as 'email'.

Comment: and php should i use if($_POST) ??